# Submit form with e.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

How would I go on about submitting a form intercepted by jQuery having used `e.preventDefault()`? Apparently it won't submit if I just call `$(form).submit()`. Below is an example of my current script.

```
$(form).submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Code...

    if (true) {
        $(form).submit();
    } else {
        // Code...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are causing recursive calls to the event handler by calling the jQuery `submit` method(The jQuery `submit` method will invoke the handler again where the prevent default is called thus blocking the default action), instead you can just call the `form` element's `submit` method so that the event handler will not get called again

```js
$(form).submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var self = this;

  // Code...

  if (true) {
    self.submit();
  } else {
    // Code...
  }
});
```

Comment: Welp, don't I feel stupid now. I should've seen that coming. Thanks though!

Comment: `var form = this;` seems redundant here

Comment: @A.Wolff yes... did that since the OP didn't share the complete code... so don't know what `form` is

Comment: @ArunPJohny You are correct but in this case `this.submit();` would make code more readable imho, avoiding redefining localy an already existing variable

Answer (score 3):

Call native DOM method instead:

```
form.submit();
```

This doesn't fire `submit` event bound with jQuery method.